# Why isn't my local.xml working?

Tags: magento-1.9, xml, local.xml

I am trying to remove a block and switch the product page to 2-columns right. Here is the code-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="left">
            <remove name="catalog.leftnav" />
        </reference>
    <catalog_product_view>
         <reference name="root">
             <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
         </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
    </default>
</layout>
```

I have it placed in app/design/frontend/default/themename/layout

I have flushed the cache and made sure the proper theme is selected in system-->configuration-->design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout file is not correct. You are defining a layout handle in another layout handle. Please try below layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="left">
            <remove name="catalog.leftnav" />
        </reference>
    </default>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="root">
             <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

I hope it will help..

Comment: I have spent about 6 hours working on this and that did it. Thank you so much.